# Automate download candidate attachment from each candidate webpage using selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

Image 1 shows a Recruitment tool, where the inbox here contains 3 candidates: HR, RJ, IE.
The candidate name, colored blue contains a hyperlink, on which if clicked, it will show another webpage.

What I would like to achieve:
For each candidate in inbox, click on the hyperlink on the candidate name, then on the candidate page, download the CV (image 2 and image 3).

The steps to get to the Inbox page within the Recruitment tool are all configured.
The only problem I am still trying to figure out is how to loop the process once in the inbox step.

How I did it for just the first candidate:

```
   #click on the candidate name ('Hane')...
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="cdk-drop-list-20"]/div[1]/orgos-recruiting-kanban-card/orgos-container/orgos-column-container/orgos-column/orgos-column-container/orgos-column[2]/kenjo-truncate-text[1]/div[2]/div/span/a').click()
    
    #inside the candidate page, find the element with 3 dots and click on it so that the download button becomes visible
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/orgos-web-app/orgos-cloud-shell/div/div/div/div/div/orgos-recruiting-candidate-main/div/div/div/orgos-column-container/orgos-column[2]/orgos-recruiting-candidate-attachments/orgos-container/orgos-table/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/kenjo-icon/mat-icon'
                               ))).click()
    
    #click on the download button
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
        '//*[@id="mat-menu-panel-10"]/div/button[3]'))).click()

    # Go back to the main inbox
    driver.back()
```

The inbox content is shown in the 4th image, which div class seems to be

```
"_ngcontent-rop-c418 ckdroplist
cdkdroplistsortingdisabled class="cdk-drop-list
rpk-dropping-area"
```

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]